# Order Objects Compare

Tags: java, object, comparator, comparable

This is my object:

```
public class TrackUserChanges{
    private Long id;
    private Long previous;
}
```

I have an ArrayList. I want to sort the Objects like this:
- if getPrevious() from one object is equal to getId from another object, put the first object the one with the that value on getId().

I have already a compareTo method in the class and I don't want to break that. So i created a method :

```
public int compareTrack(TrackUserChanges o){

    if(this.getPrevious().equals((o.getId()))){
        return -1;
    }
    ??return this.getPrevious().compareTo(o.getId());

}
```

It's not good. Any ideas?

Example: id,previous

```
TrackUserChanges t = new TrackUserChanges ( 2,1)
TrackUserChanges t1 = new TrackUserChanges ( 3,1)
TrackUserChanges t2 = new TrackUserChanges ( 1,1)
```

In this case t.getPrevious() = t2.getId() then i want this order : t2,t,t1

Comment: I don't understand the part "put the first object the one with the that value on getId()."

Comment: I think what you you're trying to do is... `this.getPrevious().getId() == o.getId()`; no? Assuming Id is primitive.

Comment: You could also create a Comparator which would hold the `compareTrack` sort logic.

Comment: @Smutje I want to order in such a way that I put first the one with that id that it's found in getPrevious()

Comment: Example: id,previous

TrackUserChanges t = new TrackUserChanges ( 2,1)
TrackUserChanges t1 = new TrackUserChanges ( 3,1)
TrackUserChanges t2 = new TrackUserChanges ( 1,1)
In this case t.getPrevious() = t2.getId() then i want this order : t2,t,t1

Comment: It's [this.compareTo(that)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#method_detail), but what I don't get is why you're comparing an instance that is the previous to the instance calling the comparison. Perhaps, call it - `comparePrevious(...)`? Please don't put code in comments :)

Comment: Note that if you do use `Comparator`, you should be wary of consistency with `#equals` (which in your case won't be the case). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to do is not a good idea.

Please read the contract for `compareTo()`:

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) ==
>   -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an
>   exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>   ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies
>   that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.

If you have `a(1,2)` and `b(2,1)`, they are not going to be reflexive: both `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` are returning same sign, which violate first rule.

You haven't thought of how to handle comparation between `a(1,2)` and `b(3,4)`. I doubt if you can make it transitive and reflexive.

Tell us why you need to do it and probably there are better choices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare like things.

```
    public class TrackUserChanges {
        private Long    id;
        private Long    previous;
    }

    public int compareTrack(TrackUserChanges o) {
        int diff = this.getId().compareTo(o.getId()); 
        if (diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        } else {
            return this.getPrevious().compareTo(o.getPrevious());
        }
    }
```

You can't compare the id to the previous, even though they are both Long values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Comparator` as follows, though I think this is inadvisable for reasons to follow:

```
// XXX: Untested code
public int compare(TrackUserChanges tuc1, TrackUserChanges tuc2) {
    return tuc1.getId() - tuc2.getPreviousId(); 
}
```

or... ordering by previous id then current id:

```
// XXX: Untested code
public int compare(TrackUserChanges tuc1, TrackUserChanges tuc2) {
    int cmp = tuc1.getId() - tuc2.getPreviousId();
    if (cmp == 0) {
       cmp = tuc1.getId() - tuc2.getId();
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Note though that if you do use `Comparator`, you should be wary of consistency with `#equals`. In your case these will be inconsistent as `#equals` should compare "like" fields as being equal. See [java Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). From Comparator:

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

So, you can't use `Comparator` if you plan to use a sorted Collection. Could you alternatively just sort by `#previousId` then `id` as in:

```
// XXX: Untested code
public int compare(TrackUserChanges tuc1, TrackUserChanges tuc2) {
    int cmp = tuc1.getPreviousId() - tuc2.getPreviousId();
    if (cmp == 0) {
       cmp = tuc1.getId() - tuc2.getId();
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

This would order naturally by only the previous id (then the id). So, for:

```
TrackUserChanges t = new TrackUserChanges(2,1);    //id, previousId
TrackUserChanges t1 = new TrackUserChanges(3,1);
TrackUserChanges t2 = new TrackUserChanges(1,1);
```

You would still get:
    t2, t, t1

For:

```
TrackUserChanges t3 = new TrackUserChanges(5,2);    //id, previousId
TrackUserChanges t4 = new TrackUserChanges(6,2);
TrackUserChanges t5 = new TrackUserChanges(7,1)
```

You would get (ordered by `previousId` then `id`): 
    (previousId=1)   t2, t, t1, t5, 
    (previousId=2)   t3, t4

This would enable you to implement a consistent `compareTo` and `#equals` for use in `SortedSet` and `TreeMap` for example.